# I can't find executable file for sendmail?

Tags: sendmail

I did a source install sendmail 8.14.4, and BerkeleyDB.4.1.

Has been the installation successfully compile .

As far as I know, 
With the installation of the source, And made ​​a copy to /usr/sbin/ sendmail the new version of sendmail using the command cp.

But i can't find sendmail file (below refer). There is no executable file .

```
root@ip-192-168-10-152:/usr/local/sendmail/sendmail-8.14.4/obj.Linux.3.13.0-24-generic.x86_64/sendmail# 
ll sendmail*


lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jun 30 08:15 sendmail.0.dist -> ../../sendmail/sendmail.0

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jun 30 08:15 sendmail.8 -> ../../sendmail/sendmail.8

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jun 30 08:15 sendmail.h -> ../../sendmail/sendmail.h
```

Isn't compile not propely??

Why is it ?

```
==========The environment set at compile ==============

root@ip-192-168-10-152:/usr/local/sendmail/sendmail-8.14.4/devtools/Site# cat site.config.m4

APPENDDEF(`confINCDIRS', `-I/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.1/include')

APPENDDEF(`confLIBDIRS', `-L/usr/local/BerkeleyDB.4.1/lib')

APPENDDEF(`confLIBS', `-ldb -lpthread')

==========================================================
```

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Maybe try it on ServerFault?

Answer (score 0):

As the previous comment states this really isn't a programming question... but you could try this via ssh...

```
locate sendmail
```